# mkdir -p returns error " file exists"

Tags: shell, aix

I tried `mkdir -p /a/b/c` on AIX. When `a` and `b` didn't exist, this command created `a`, `b` and `c`. But when `a` and `b` both exists, it gives an error

> Cannot create /a/b. /a/b: File exists

and returns an error code 2.

Any help on this?

Comment: Any help with what? What's the problem? That is the intended output. Besides that, this is not on-topic at Stack Overflow. You should repost it at [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) and delete the question here.

Comment: There is a file in `/a/b/c`, so you cannot create a dir. Check it with `file /a/b/c`.

Comment: Are you quite certain `a/b` is a directory? If so, this is non-posix-conformant ([Each dir operand that names an existing directory shall be ignored without error.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/mkdir.html))

Answer (score 2):

I just came across a similar symptom - except that it was a broken remote mountpoint (in this case using sshfs) and had nothing to do with a *file* being "in the way":

```
$ mkdir -p /mnt/sshfs-remote
mkdir: cannot create directory `/mnt/sshfs-remote': File exists
$ ls -lscrath /mnt/sshfs-remote
/bin/ls: cannot access /mnt/sshfs-remote: No such file or directory
$ ls -lscrath /mnt
/bin/ls: cannot access /mnt/sshfs-remote: No such file or directory
total 4.0K
    ? d?????????  ? ?    ?        ?            ? sshfs-remote/
```

A umount* sorted it out. I've also added an exception into the script that triggered the error to also try umount.

```
$ umount -l /mnt/sshfs-remote ; mount /mnt/sshfs-remote
$ ls -lsahd /mnt/sshfs-remote
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6 Mar 11 09:20 /mnt/sshfs-remote/
$ mkdir -p /mnt/sshfs-remote
$ echo $?
0
```

---

*In case someone is wondering about the -l I used on umount: It is probably unnecessary - but on remote mounts I've found it to be a cleaner/easier way to just "get on with it". From the umount man page:

> ```
>    -l, --lazy
>           Lazy unmount.  Detach the filesystem from the file hierarchy now, and clean up all references to this filesystem as soon
>           as it is not busy anymore.  (Requires kernel 2.4.11 or later.)
> ```

Comment: This works, for me, i had to use `umount -f "full path of the dir"`. It was weird, it won't even display the folder that was mounted when doing `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen using Parallels filesystem. The virtual machine complained about  a directory existing, even though "ls" could not see it. When I cd'ed into the directory, it allowed it, but then ls would fail. So it seemed to be a filesystem caching bug. I solved it by going to the host machine and creating the directory with a file, then going back to the virtual machine and deleting the directory. After that, the virtual machine filesystem was synced properly and I could create the directory with mkdir as normal.

On VM:

```
> mkdir -p build/a/b/c  <-- failed with "file exists"
> cd build              <-- allowed
> ls                    <-- failed
```

On host machine:

```
> mkdir build
> touch build/foo
```

On VM:

```
> rm -rf build
> mkdir -p build/a/b/c    <-- Success
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking  about this scenario:

```
bash-2.02# mkdir -p /a/c/d
bash-2.02# rm -rf /a/c/d
bash-2.02# mkdir -p /a/c/d
mkdir: cannot create /a/c
/a/c: File exists
bash-2.02# echo $?
2
bash-2.02#
```

Comment: yes, even though "a" and "b" are directories, it says "file exists" and I ran the command "mkdir -p /a/b/c", still the error says " /a/b exists". There is no file with the same name. I think mkdir -p should create every directory in the path(if there is no file with the same name)

Comment: @vik123 How does this answer the question?